# JSP 2.0 with RichFaces 4 don't work on JBoss 7

Tags: jsp, richfaces

i have a problem with my app, after deploying it on server i'm getting errors in log:

```
15:12:45,359 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-5) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/content/FiboRichFaces.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-core-impl-4.2.1.Final.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl': java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:293) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.setResourceHandler(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:766) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:313) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:263) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.<init>(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:62) [richfaces-core-impl-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function from [Module "deployment.FiboRichFaces.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 22 more

15:12:45,399 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/FiboRichFaces]] (MSC service thread 1-5) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/content/FiboRichFaces.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-core-impl-4.2.1.Final.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl': java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/content/FiboRichFaces.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-core-impl-4.2.1.Final.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl': java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:293) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.setResourceHandler(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:766) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:313) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:263) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.<init>(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:62) [richfaces-core-impl-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function from [Module "deployment.FiboRichFaces.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 22 more

15:12:45,414 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Error listenerStart
15:12:45,414 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Context [/FiboRichFaces] startup failed due to previous errors
15:12:45,415 SEVERE [javax.faces] (MSC service thread 1-5) Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
15:12:45,416 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-5) Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1004) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:316) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:328) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3489) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3999) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3917) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]

15:12:45,420 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./FiboRichFaces: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./FiboRichFaces: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]

15:12:45,624 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "FiboRichFaces.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./FiboRichFaces" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./FiboRichFaces: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
15:12:45,632 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment FiboRichFaces.war
15:12:45,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment FiboRichFaces.war in 38ms
15:12:45,663 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./FiboRichFaces: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./FiboRichFaces: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
```

**Environment**

- Server: JBoss Web 7.0.10 Final
- Servlet Specification: 3.0
- JSP Version: 2.0

**WEB-INF/lib**

- richfaces-components-api-4.2.1.Final.jar
- richfaces-components-ui-4.2.1.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-api-4.2.1.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-impl-4.2.1.Final.jar
- sac-1.3.jar
- validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
- cssparser-0.9.5.jar
- guava-r07-sources.jar
- annotations-4.0.0.Final.jar

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>FiboRichBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>bean.FiboRichBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

I'm fighting with it many hours... when i resolve one issue another takes it place.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the root cause of your exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
```

So, [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is missing in the webapp's runtime classpath.

And indeed, in your list of JARs you've only the Guava source code file:

> - guava-r07-sources.jar

You need the JAR file with class files instead, not the JAR file with  source code files. You need the one without "-sources" in the filename.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you should not be using the ancient JSP view technology, but instead its successor [Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info). Otherwise you won't be able to utilize the full JSF 2 powers.